# How can I access the Kamailio configuration file from the KEMI script?

Tags: python, voip, kamailio

I need to access defines and variables from the Kamailio configuration file in my Python script. So far, I am able to access the global variables only through `self.my_var = int(KSR.pv.get("$sel(cfg_get.my_group.my_var)"))` where this variable is defined in the configuration file as `my_group.my_var = 664.` How can I access the definitions (to know that `#!ifdef MY_DEFINE` succeeds or not)? Or at least the configuration file to read them myself ?

I found nothing about on the [official documentation](https://kamailio.org/docs/tutorials/devel/kamailio-kemi-framework/) and even `$sel(cfg_get.my_group.my_var)` I found it elsewhere.

**UPDATE** These values are not normally available at runtime (preprocessing), so the native code can use them like this:

```
   #!define WITH_SIPTRACE
   #!substdef "!SERVER_ID!654!g"
   ...
   request_route {
    
    #!ifdef WITH_SIPTRACE
        xlog("L_NOTICE", "$C(yx)========= server_id=SERVER_ID NEW $rm $pr:$si:$sp$C(xx)\n");
    #!endif
    ...
```

Can this same behavior be achieved in Python ?

**UPDATE 2** Found partial answer (below) in `KSR.kx.get_def()` and `KSR.kx.get_defn()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change defines. There is no mechanism for that.

To make configurable parameters, use database or curl module + in-memory cache via htable module.

Here is htable optimization for auth, for example

```
AUTH WITH CACHING
# authentication with password caching using htable
modparam("htable", "htable", "auth=>size=10;autoexpire=300;")
modparam("auth_db", "load_credentials", "$avp(password)=password")
route[AUTHCACHE] {
if($sht(auth=>$au::passwd)!=$null) {
if (!pv_auth_check("$fd", "$sht(auth=>$au::passwd)", "0", "1")) {
auth_challenge("$fd", “1”);
exit;
}
} else {
# authenticate requests
if (!auth_check("$fd", "subscriber", "1")) {
auth_challenge("$fd", "0");
exit;
}
$sht(auth=>$au::passwd) = $avp(password);
}
# user authenticated - remove auth header
if(!is_method("REGISTER|PUBLISH"))
consume_credentials();
}
```

Here is how to get info from db using sql.

https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.0.x/modules/avpops.html#avpops.f.avp_db_query

```
avp_db_query("select password, ha1 from subscriber where username='$tu'",
    "$avp(i:678);$avp(i:679)");
```

As opensource sample of such optimization you can see code of kazoo project.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for not being clear, but I am using Python (through KEMI), not Kamailio's native language. Also, I am not trying to change the defines, only to know what is defined and what is not.

Comment: Defines are pre-processing directives. All that are executed only once at startup to make valid config. Like in C/C++. There are no any defines nor excluded config sections in runtime at all.

Comment: Here is the description of how pre-processing works. On Kamailio it is exactly the same. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-preprocessors/

Comment: Ok. Could you, please, show me the Python code that knows the value of a defined value ?

Comment: os.system("grep KEY /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg|cut -f 2 -d\= ")

Comment: Again, those values are in config only. Kamailio do NOT know about that at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question ... Compared to my dumb solution, it is not clear how your solution answers the question.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot use that Python code: there could be more configuration files and/or different locations. You cannot know these value at runtime, of course, but you DO take actions accordingly in the native code. I simply want the same possibility for Python. –

Comment: you should not use defines as you propose. It is pre-processor staff. Nothing to add. If you do not understand what is pre-processor, please take some time and read the article above.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I dislike because it adds extra variables for each interesting definition.

On the configuration side:

```
####### Custom Parameters #########
/*
    Is there a better method to access these flags (!define)?
    For the constants (!substdef) there are KSR.kx.get_def(), KSR.kx.get_defn().
*/

#!ifdef WITH_OPTIONA
my_group.option_a = yes
#!else
my_group.option_a = no
#!endif

 #!ifdef WITH_OPTIONB
my_group.option_b = yes
#!else
my_group.option_b = no
#!endif
```

On the Python side:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.my_domain = KSR.kx.get_def("MY_DOMAIN")
    self.server_id = KSR.kx.get_defn("SERVER_ID")
    assert self.my_domain and self.server_id

    self.flags = None
    self.initialized = False

def real_init(self):
    '''
        Object data is initialized here, dynamically,
            because__init__ and child_init are called too early.
    '''
    def read_flags():
        flags = {}
        for i in ['option_a', 'option_b']:
            value = bool(int(KSR.pv.get("$sel(cfg_get.my_group.{})".format(i))))
            if value:
                flags[i[len('option_'):]] = True
        return flags
    self.flags = read_flags()

    self.initialized = True
```

**Update** Partial solution found: `!substdef` constants, but not `!define` ones.

**Update 5.5.2** KSR.kx.ifdef() and KSR.kx.ifndef() added on the master branch, but not yet exported in a official release (the latest being 5.5.2)
See [kemix: added KSR.kx.ifdef() and KSR.kx.ifndef()](https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/commit/851a8c0f0c8f7cc7ab22cb905bdb3987e9fa461b).